# OpenGL ES - camera look at touch position

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a camera (main view, projection). I create it here:

```
-(void)setupProjection
{
    // Generate a perspective matrix with a 60 degree FOV
    float aspect = self.frame.size.width / self.frame.size.height;
    ksMatrixLoadIdentity(&_projectionMatrix);
    ksPerspective(&_projectionMatrix, 60.0, aspect, 0.01f, 50.0f);
    ksTranslate(&_projectionMatrix, 0.0, -0.295, 0.0);

    // Defaul value
    mFloatScale = 0.5;

    // Load projection matrix
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionSlot, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&_projectionMatrix.m[0][0]);
}
```

Also I have gesture recognizer. So I want when my user move finger he will rotate camera like in first person shooters games. How can I update my projection matrix? I think I must create something like lookAt function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a method to generate the `lookAt` matrix or create your own. It is an easy equation found on web.

Once you have this what I suggest is you store 3 vectors representing your camera as `position`, `forward`, `up`. These will be inserted into the `lookAt` method (`center = position+forward`).

Now at this point you may implement quite a few variations of camera movement. The omni situation would be to create an additional vector `right` which is a cross product of `forward` and `up`. Then:

- Turn left/right: `forward += right*someRotationSpeedFactor`
- Turn up/down: `forward += up*someRotationSpeedFactor`
- Tilt left/right: `up += right*someRotationSpeedFactor`
- Move forward/backwards: `position += forward*someSpeedFactor`
- Move up/down: `position += up*someSpeedFactor`
- Move sideways: `position += right*someSpeedFactor`

Changing the direction means negative factor. The factors are usually received from either the user input (the distance of two touch events) or current speed. After using any of these equations you need to renormalize the changed vectors for `forward` and `up` (divide them by their distance). Also you need to recompute the effected vector `forward` or `up` if any by again using a cross product. For instance if you turn up you will change the `forward` vector but the `up` vector is effected by it as well. That means you need to set the `up` vector as a cross product of `forward` and `right` vectors. It sounds confusing in theory but in practice it looks something like this:

```
- (void)turnUp:(CGFloat)scale {
    vector forward = self.forward;
    vector up = self.up;
    vector right = cross(self.forward, self.up);

    self.forward = normalized(forward + up*scale);
    self.up = cross(self.forward, right);
}
```

Now this procedure is quite good for something like piloting a space craft or a jet for instance. But the first person shooters are usually a bit more restricted as the `up` vector must always face upwards your display. The tilt is then not implemented and in some games you have a restriction as to maximum upwards angle. This is due to the math issue in this case. Anyway in general if you simply leave the `up` vector unchanged you should do fine but you might need to normalize the `right` vector after computing it as it will not have a length of 1 anymore.